# Expand plotting area of raster::plot

Tags: raster, r, plot

I have a [raster](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1o1kxxgumK6Uk65bMUeln9AWxOv1ITlwo/view?usp=sharing) that I'd like to plot in the Azimuthal Equidistant projection with a grid and labels.  So far I've been able to do that.  However, I cannot get the labels inside the plotting area.  They are always cut off.

I have tried most of the par() options such as playing with par(mar), par(oma), and par(usr).  Hard to tell, but I think the par("usr") option does not work with raster::plot.  I also tried playing around with the extent of the raster, since R bases the plot size on the coordinate range of the initial data, but that also did not work.  Below is my code and cut off labels.

```
GSmean<-stack("[file][1]") 
parallels <- c(80, 70, 60)
meridians <- seq(-180, 160, by = 30)
mlim <- c(-180, 180)
plim <- c(50, 80)
grat <- graticule(lons = meridians, lats = parallels, xlim = mlim, ylim = plim, proj = projection(GSmean))
labs <- graticule_labels(meridians, parallels, xline = 360, yline =46, proj = projection(GSmean))

#new plot
breaks<-c(-1,0,1,2,999)
cols <- c("darkgreen", "darkred","gray81","gray81")
plot(GSmean, col=cols,breaks=breaks,axes=F,legend=FALSE,box=FALSE)
plot(grat, add = TRUE, lty = 3,col="honeydew3")
text(labs, lab = parse(text= labs$lab), 
     col= c("gray30", "gray30")[labs$islon + 1], cex = 0.85)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `xpd = NA` to the `text()` call to prevent clipping.

Here's a stab at an example:

```
library(raster)
library(graticule)
p <- projectExtent(raster(extent(-180, 180, 50, 90), crs = "+proj=longlat"), 
               "+proj=laea +lat_0=90")
res(p) <- 50000
data("wrld_simpl", package = "maptools")

p <- rasterize(sp::spTransform(subset(wrld_simpl, coordinates(wrld_simpl)[,2] > 0), projection(p)), p)
parallels <- c(80, 70, 60)
meridians <- seq(-180, 160, by = 30)    
mlim <- c(-180, 180)
plim <- c(50, 80)
grat <- graticule(lons = meridians, lats = parallels, xlim = mlim, ylim = plim, proj = projection(p))
labs <- graticule_labels(meridians, parallels, xline = 360, yline =46, proj = projection(p))

#new plot
plot(p, axes=F,legend=FALSE,box=FALSE)
plot(grat, add = TRUE, lty = 3,col="honeydew3")
text(labs, lab = parse(text= labs$lab), 
 col= c("gray30", "gray30")[labs$islon + 1], cex = 0.85,xpd = NA)
```

[image]

Comment: That did it.  I knew it was somewhere little....
Also, @mdsumner, I used your blog [post](http://mdsumner.github.io/graticule/articles/graticule.html) for help with adding the lat/lon lines and labels. Thank you for the work you do.